# Why don't we use the same connector for all digital signals?

Tags: usb, connector, digital-communications

A modern PC typically has a lot of connectors, including USB ports, displayport and HDMI ports, and ethernet ports. My understanding is that all of these are digital connections that are designed for transferring large amounts of data.

Instead of having all of these different connectors, and maintaining multiple independent standards, why not just have, say, 15 USB ports on the back of the computer, and then have all peripherals and networking use this same port as well?

Comment: Why are there different sized cars on the road?

Comment: Please see https://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: @crasic So are you saying that the only consideration here is throughput? Because it seems that USB, displayport, and Ethernet for instance all overlap in what they support. I.E. a USB port may support 10Gb/s, an HDMI 1.4 port will do about the same.

Comment: @PeterBennett haha, I knew that reference was coming. But mice, keyboards, webcams, and even external storage devices all usually use USB already so I was wondering what makes other cases like networking or graphics different.

Comment: Apple would like to see just one connector too and to that end have been pushing more and more functionality through the USB-C/Thunderbolt/Displayport/Power connector. Macbooks only have pretty much only USB-C connectors now.

Comment: No, I am saying the differences are user requirements and expectations.

Comment: @crasic Could you give an example of one of those requirements? This is exactly what I am trying to figure out with this question.

Comment: You think one connector should be all we need, huh? Communist!

Comment: What the world wanted was powered ethernet. What the world got was USB.

Comment: @TrevorGalivan Graphics are much MUCH faster and work over much much shorter distances than mice or keyboards. Do you want a mouse and keyboard that uses a wire that can only be 6" long with a ton of wires and is a thousand times faster than it needs to be? Ethernet is fast and may or may not be comparable to the newest USB but it is also designed to work over long distances and has extra electrical safety hardware as a result and is therefore big and expensive so you don't want all that extra stuff when you don't need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons, but I think one of the big ones is the speed of the various signals. Take, for example, USB 2.0 and USB 3.0:

[image: USB 3 pinout]

Source: https://theydiffer.com/difference-between-usb-2-0-and-3-0-cables/

USB 3 adds those extra five pins at the top, which are used in SuperSpeed mode (total bandwidth of 5 Gbps, which is much faster than USB 2!) To carry such fast signals, you need higher-quality cables, which are more expensive. Designing circuits capable of such speeds is also more complex--you might need to go from a 2 layer to a 4 or 6 layer impedance-controlled circuit board, or you might need to use more expensive ICs.

There are many things that just don't *need* that extra speed (think of peripherals like a mouse or keyboard) and forcing everything to use one very high quality standard would just drive both prices and complexity up.

You can see this with the current mess that is the various types of USB Type-C cable. The different types of "USB-C cable" have different capabilities--some can only do USB 2.0 speeds, some support SuperSpeed, others support even faster standards like Thunderbolt, some support Power Delivery. You *could* just get the best, most capable cable for everything, but that gets very expensive very quickly.

Comment: +1 for the photo and new info

Comment: Yet Ethernet supports 1Gbps which is fast enough for most users but overkill ($) for a mouse

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 this is rapidly changing, the cost of gigabit ethernet is rapidly approaching the cost of USB. There are MCU on market with integrated PHY's, there are profile based protocols for IP based applications, reducing the overhead of software stack and development. Furthermore there are families of MCUs with integrated hardware acceleration for the ip stack itself. I am pointing this out because in my perspective your view is a little outdated vis a vis the state of the technology. Integration is constantly increasing and reducing the price point.

Comment: Agreed. That’s why simple serial and parallel ports for interfacing are obsolete. But the cost of obsolescence must be factored in your analysis. Which assumptions did you make about my understanding.?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 many assumptions, it's an interesting topic and thanks for your insight .

Comment: yes too many...